# Servlet 3.0 AsyncContext returns response at timeout

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I followed [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html?page=3) tutorial and implemented a simple chat application.
I'm testing it both in latest Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome browsers.

My main concern is that the messaging exchange does not seem to happen in real time. Even though the all the server processing happens in less than a second from the request, the browser gets the response just after the `AsyncContext` timeout is exceeded.

Even is the default 10 seconds or a custom value added through `AsyncContext.setTimeout()` the time of response is the same with the timeout. Should this be the expected behaviour? Is there a way to force the server to send the response as soon as it is ready and not wait the hole timeout interval?

Comment: Are you running off local host?

Comment: @FaddishWorm The application is running on Tomcat7 on the localhost.

Comment: There are a few comments in that article that say there may be threading issues. I will check it out next time im near my tomcat server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may have forgotten to `complete` the async context. Java 6 docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#complete()

```
watcherExecutor.execute(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                           // publish a new bid event to a watcher
                           aCtx.getResponse().getWriter().print("A new bid on the item was placed. The current price ..., next bid price is ...");
                           aCtx.complete();
                        };
                     });
```